How to send asynchronous httpwebrequest request in VB?
So I am doing some web scraping in VB.NET using this approach:
First I declare some public variables in a module.
Public str_url As String, code_result As String
Public webreq As HttpWebRequest
Public webresp As HttpWebResponse
Public datastream As Stream

This is for reusability sake and to save runtime resources. Then when I press the button for web scraping, I use these variables as
Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    str_url = txtUrl.Text
    webreq = WebRequest.Create(str_url)
    webresp = CType(webreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    datastream = webresp.GetResponseStream()
    Dim res As New StreamReader(datastream)
    txtResult.Text = res.ReadToEnd()
End Sub

This is working fine, except for the fact that during the time that the data is being read from the site, the app/form becomes unresponsive and becomes responsive/enabled only after the data has been read from the target website.
Is there any way I can make this asynchronous so that the application does not become unresponsive during the time that data is being awaited from the website, and other tasks can be performed? VB is an event driven language after all.

Take the initialization and the pieces you need from here: Understand HttpWebRequest in KeepAlive mode -- As you can notice, the HttpWebResponse, the response Stream, and any other disposable object you create must be declare with Using statements. I also suggest you set Option Strict to ON and keep it so -- A better suggestion is: migrate to HttpClient, WebRequest belongs to the history books

@Jimi can you guide me to any good HttpClient tutorials please? I know VB6 but am new to the .NET platform.

@Jimi thanks I resolved my issue with the use of HttpClient. If you post your suggestion as an answer with an example, I will mark it as accepted/resolved.

Get the HttpClient initialization and sample async calls from here: HttpClient with latest User Agent being out of date?. Read the notes and the comments, since you're trying to scrape stuff from some Web Site
